# Kubespray with bastion and custom SSH port + agent forwarding

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, kubespray

Is it possible to use Kubespray with Bastion but on custom port and with agent forwarding? If it is not supported, what changes does one need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always, since you can configure that at three separate levels: via the host user's `~/.ssh/config`, via the entire playbook with `group_vars`, or as inline config (that is, on the command line or in the inventory file).

The ssh config is hopefully straightforward:

```
Host 1.2.* *.example.com # or whatever pattern matches the target instances
  ProxyJump someuser@some-bastion:1234
  # and then the Agent should happen automatically, unless you mean
  # ForwardAgent yes
```

I'll speak to the inline config next, since it's a little simpler:

```
ansible-playbook -i whatever \
    -e '{"ansible_ssh_common_args": "-o ProxyJump=\"someuser@jump-host:1234\""}' \
    cluster.yaml
```

or via the inventory in the same way:

```
master-host-0 ansible_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_ssh_common_args="-o ProxyJump='someuser@jump-host:1234'"
```

or via `group_vars`, which you can either add to an existing `group_vars/all.yml`, or if it doesn't exist then create that `group_vars` directory containing the `all.yml` file as a child of the directory containing your inventory file

If you have more complex ssh config than you wish to encode in the inventory/command-line/group_vars, you can also instruct the ansible-invoked ssh to use a dedicated config file via the [`ansible_ssh_extra_args`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/intro_inventory.html?highlight=ansible_ssh_extra_args#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) variable:

```
ansible-playbook -e '{"ansible_ssh_extra_args": "-F /path/to/special/ssh_config"}' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case where I needed to access the hosts on particular ports, I just had to modify the host's `~/.ssh/config` to be:

```
Host 10.40.45.102
  ForwardAgent yes
  User root
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -p 44057 root@example.com

Host 10.40.45.104
  ForwardAgent yes
  User root
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -p 44058 root@example.com
```

Where `10.40.*` was the internal IPs.